# How to display phantoms in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext3

I read this description: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-3118/21270/23

So I tried this in the sublime console:

```
view.erase_phantoms("test"); view.add_phantom("test",
view.sel()[0], "<img src=/home/v/4.png>",
sublime.LAYOUT_BLOCK)
```

Unfortunately the image was not displayed!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although I don't think it's mentioned in that thread, there is a bit of documentation on [minihtml](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/minihtml.html) available. The crux of what's wrong with your snippet is the way you're specifying the image URL; it doesn't have one of the supported URL schemes (`http://`, `file://`, `res://` or `data:`).

You may also want to provide extra CSS/HTML markup to style the image (e.g. dimensions). The only images I had available for testing are rather large and I was seeing that without an explicit size, Sublime was making some assumptions about the dimensions to use to display them.

Here's an example of a tweaked version of your code (reformatted slightly to make it easier to see what's going on in my image):

```python
image = "file:///home/tmartin/speaker.png"
html = '<img src="' + image + '" width="32" height="32">'
view.erase_phantoms ("test")
view.add_phantom ("test", view.sel()[0], html, sublime.LAYOUT_BLOCK)
```

[edit]Whoops, typo in my image, the call to erase_phantoms should pass `test` as the parameter, not `text`. The code above is correct.[/edit]

[image: Sample Phantom Usage]

Comment: The Sublime Text [API page](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) does not mention there is a `view.add_phantom` or anything related to view member methods. Does they were removed since this answer was written?

Comment: @user I don't think they were ever documented actually. This answer is based on a modified version of the example that the question had in it, which is based on the sample that Jon provided when the dev build that introduced the feature was announced. The API still exists but isn't documented because you should use `PhantomSet`s to manage your phantoms instead (which use this API behind the scenes).